# Angular 6 app crashing on Googlebot / PhantomJS. Missing shims?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 6 app which runs great in browsers, but crashes when Googlebot tries to scrape it.

**My theory:** it's an issue of Javascript compatability, and TypeScript is outputting JS that isn't compatible with Googlebot.

**The question:** What shims does my Angular app need so that it doesn't crash when Googlebot tries to scrape it? Is there anything else I can do to maximize compatibility?

Because Googlebot does not offer `console.log` outputs, I started my testing by trying to screencap my site with PhantomJS, which (rumor has it) is what Google uses.

When I do so, I get the following console error (I am not certain, but I presume this is what Googlebot is running into as well):

```
 https://www.example.com/ng2/vendor.js:46405 in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Array(HEADER_OFFSET).fill(null)')

  https://www.example.com/ng2/vendor.js:46407 in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
  https://www.example.com/ng2/runtime.js:82 in __webpack_require__
  https://www.example.com/ng2/main.js:1815 in ./src/main.ts
  https://www.example.com/ng2/runtime.js:82 in __webpack_require__
  https://www.example.com/ng2/main.js:1863
  https://www.example.com/ng2/runtime.js:82 in __webpack_require__
  https://www.example.com/ng2/runtime.js:44 in checkDeferredModules
  https://www.example.com/ng2/runtime.js:31 in webpackJsonpCallback
```

It seems like PhantomJS is running into this line of code in vendor.js and is getting hung up:

```
var HEADER_FILLER = new Array(HEADER_OFFSET).fill(null);
```

Is there any kind of polyfill I can add so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: You may head over to the GH and ask them since it's part of something they were recently committing for I think, Line 71 in [this core file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/instructions.ts)

Comment: Any luck with this? Facing the same issue and am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @Kiran Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue and get Googlebot to render Angular apps properly, I had to open my app's polyfills.ts file and make the following changes:

```
        /* enable these */
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';

    /* ... */

    /* and these: */

    /**
    * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
    * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
    */
    import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
    /**
    * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
    */
    import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25416#issuecomment-432674395)